# How to parse following HTML file in Python and store into csv with all questions as columns and their answers as rows

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

```
<br>Questionnaire score: 0 out of 0<br>
<br>Question: 1: Present Location ? Ready to relocate?<br>
<br>Answer: Yes<br>
<br>Question: 2: Highest level of education and completion date<br>
<br>Answer: Bachelors<br>
<br>Question: 3: Are you authorized to work in UK?<br>
<br>Answer: Yes<br>
```

Questions are fixed but answers may be different. I have tried HTML parser and beautifulsoup4.

Please Help with a suitable code.
Thanks..!

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's not necessary to ask for permission, If you want to - you can do it. If you have questions - read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) most wanted framework for web scraping using python, making it super simple and easy to use.